# Control-drag event through Windows PC keyboard

Tags: macos, autolayout, xcode6.1

I am connecting to MAC machine remote from `windows laptop` to develop an app. I am planning to add constraints in xcode and the documentation says, I need to do contrl-dragging [as specified here](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/).

I couldn't find any help online on how to do this. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is confusing because Control-dragging is done the same way on a Windows PC as it is done on a Mac.

Windows laptops should have a Control key (possibly label Ctrl).  Press and hold down that key. While you're holding the Control key down, press and hold down the left mouse button. Move the mouse. You are now Control-dragging. When the mouse cursor reaches the desired destination, release the mouse button and the Control key.

If that doesn't work or help you understand, you're going to have to be clearer about the nature of your confusion or the problem.

Comment: You got it correct. I tried exactly you described, but it didn't populate the context menu as specified in the tutorial, I am stuck at that point.

Comment: What software are you using for accessing the Mac from the laptop? It may be interfering or failing to transmit the events faithfully.

Comment: I am using "windows remote desktop" from my windows 7 laptop. I tried Cntrl+D to remove a character from text file on remote mac machine, which worked. So, I am thinking Cntrl+ event getting event transferred properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, you could try a different program, such as a generic VNC client. You could also check the preferences of Windows Remote Desktop to see if there are any options to configure the behavior of Control, mouse clicks, or Control-clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you simply cannot do it, at least that way. Apple is aware of that problem that happens when you use Macincloud. The most you can do is this: https://support.macincloud.com/support/solutions/articles/8000007774-alternative-method-to-ctrl-drag-control-drag-

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.